# SQL Server 2012 - service account error

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following 2 errors when trying to install SQL server 2012 on Windows Server 2012. These occur at the server configuration page.

- Access is denied.
- The SQL Server service account login or password is not valid. Use SQL Server Configuration Manager to update the service account.

I have specified the username MYDOMAIN\sqlSvcAcc and the correct password. I am using the default instance name for SQL.

Anyone know whats causing these errors ? is it an AD issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Wasn't running as administrator. Doh !

Comment: This isn't really a good answer. Your service account should not need to run permanently as an administrator.

Comment: I think he meant he wasn't running the SQL Server installation as administrator.